# converting GUI of vb6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Thanks a lot for the received answer.the following is brief description of how my project works.
GUI is used to collect information from User and validates.have got dll named controlclass that pass input data from GUI to Business logic DLL.this dLL connect to the database and saves data.after that,it disconnected and takes the results to the control dll,then to GUI which interprets if the input data was  successful or not.Is there a tool that can be used to convert VB6 GUI to .net web forms?
am not familiar to vb.net.how do you create reference to vb6 dll or COM  from vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a reference to a VB6 COM object from VB.NET:

- Select **Project>[Your Project]** Properties *OR* Double Click on **My Project** in the Solution Explorer window
- Select the **References** tab
- Click **Add**
- Select the **COM** tab
- Select the component you require

You will notice that Visual Studio will creates an Interop assembly which handles the interfacing to the COM object for you.

From that point on accessing the COM object is the same as VB6

```
Dim obj as New MyObject
obj.DoSomething
'etc
Set obj = nothing
```